# Redirect to 'create new record' page from flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow, lightning-flow-builder

I have scenario where I have designed a flow that when new button clicked on A1, A2 or A3 object's, flow ask questions and then creates record for A1, A2 or A3 based on asnwer. As soon as user click on next I had action that rediects user to new page which is 1st question of and link given for redirect is `/lightning/o/A1__c/new` for A1 object.
It is never ending loop of question. Can somebody tell me what wrong did I do?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail about your flow, including screenshots of the specific elements.  Also clarify - when you click the link, it takes you back to the screen flow?  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

so if I well understood, the record is created, and you want to redirect user to created A1 record?
If yes, you should use such link: `/lightning/r/objectName/recordId/view`
The link you added will always direct you to the creation of the A1 record

If I understood bad, please correct me

Comment: Hi, I have not created record, in simple words my requirement is I want to run my flow between 'clicking of 'New' button and creating a record. As soon as my questions are asnwered I want to redirect my flow to page where a record is created.